# SHOW ON TRIGGER IS UNSUPPORTED

Tags: sql, triggers, show

I have created a trigger on my table. Now I want to show the trigger but on my SQL stated that

> "Show is unsupported. Skipped".

I used the following query:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS IN Ella
```

Anyone knows why or how I can see the triggers?
The table name is Ella.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `show triggers` in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and what I could found is that MariaDB has something like that.
I have created two tables and one trigger:

```
create table Ella(first_col int);

create table Ella2(first_col int);

CREATE TRIGGER test_tr 
AFTER INSERT ON Ella 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE Ella2 SET Ella2.first_col = Ella2.first_col+1;
```

And then this command works:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `Table` = 'Ella'
```

Here is more about that:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-triggers/

But as Gordon commented, if we do not know what database do you use it is only a guessing game...

> > > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d3949f5230c12d1d092d7deb2915fc71)

After few comments from OP I have realised it is probably SQLServer OP is using.
I have done a new demo where I have used this query to find a trigger for some table:

```
SELECT sysobjects.*
     , OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) AS table_name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE sysobjects.type = 'TR' 
and OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) = 'Ella'
```

> > > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4de727060a407b084eeaedb57c37b35b)

If you want to see the code of the trigger then:

```
SELECT *   
FROM sys.sql_modules  
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Ella');
```

Comment: I have tried to create 2 tables and still doesn't work. It still shows error ""Show is unsupported. Skipped".".
I'm very new on this and I don't even know my database. How can I check what kind of database I have?

Comment: Hi @Ella, first of all I want to explain that I have created two tables just for the purpose of the example in my demo. the command you need to run is : "SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `Table` = 'Ella'" Can you tell me what tool do you use ? Usualy there is a name of the tool on the top left corner of the main window.

Comment: it said SQLTools 1.8b38. Is that what you mean?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4de727060a407b084eeaedb57c37b35b

Comment: Hi @ellawidya , I have updated my answer and the second part of my answer is for SQLServer. I believe that is the database you are using...maybe not... let me know if ti works...

Comment: I've tried:
"SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE Table = 'Ella'
and also "SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE Table = "Ella"
Both don't work.

This was my query to create the trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_test_Ella
AFTER  
INSERT 
ON Ella
FOR EACH ROW   
UPDATE Ella 
SET Ella.tmstmp = Ella.tmstmp+1;


INSERT INTO Ella (ID, tmstmp, matchcode, Art)
VALUES (1596, timestamp '2020-08-28 10:52:58', 'CARO', 'insert')

I executed the trigger query, then it said that "create trigger, executed in 11 ms"

So now I want to see the triger I have created. But then it's always "Show is unsupported. Skipped".

Comment: Hi @ellawidya Have you seen the second part of my answer ?? I have given you another option for your problem in a form of a SELECT query.

Comment: I can't make the triggers with your query. It said "missing keyword before, after or instead of".
This is the query I used.
CREATE TRIGGER histo_ku 
ON Ella
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  
AS PRINT "Database Created."

Comment: Hi @ellawidya please read my whole answer. Take some time and try to read it with understanding... You will need this select to see your query: `SELECT *   
FROM sys.sql_modules  
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('histo_ku');`

Comment: Hi @ellawidya so, did it help ?